# 12 month rolling from a entered month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

Hi can someone please help me, I want to create a script with a month parameter, the results I require is the next 12 month's names as column headings.

For example if the parameter is February the results should be:

```
March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December | January | February |
```

As the column names which I want to use to fill in values at a later stage.
Can someone please advise me on this and how I can achieve this

My script I have so far don't know how to approach this

```
declare @MonthParam varchar(20) = 'March'
declare @MonthNumber int = (
Select CASE WHEN @MonthParam = 'January' THEN 1
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'February' THEN 2
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'March' THEN 3
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'April' THEN 4
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'May' THEN 5
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'June' THEN 6
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'July' THEN 7
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'August' THEN 8
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'September' THEN 9
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'October' THEN 10
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'November' THEN 11
            WHEN @MonthParam = 'December' THEN 12
END) 
WHILE(@MonthNumber < 13)

    BEGIN

    declare @month varchar(20) = DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 )
    declare @sql varchar(max)
    set @sql = 'select val as ' + @month + ' from t'
    exec (@sql)

    SET @MonthNumber = @MonthNumber + 1;

    END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? What have you tried - show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I am using sql 2008 R2, I have the following script so far but I want it in one result set

Comment: `I have the following script... ` where is the script?

Comment: I will add my script as a answer its too big

Comment: NO!! add it on your question.

Comment: It does not fit here

Comment: I will delete my answer now just want you to see the script

Comment: I know this might not be the way to achieve this at all just don't know how to approach this

Comment: @LeeRoy what values do you what to display for the columns, can you provide sample data an desired output (with results). in other words, how do you know the value in ` t ` belongs to which column

Comment: I want to pass a month name to the parameter and the result should be 12 month's names excluding the entered one so if I enter "January" it should return a result set with the rest of the month's name as column heading with no value for each. So meaning February, March, April, May and so on for the next 12 months. Sorry does this make some sense?

Comment: My example is just a first try so not sure it is close to correct...

Comment: I've been looking at this a while, and the way you've asked, it looks like the answer from @ElementZero is close to what you want. And perhaps exactly, but I can't help feeling that whatever the problem is you're trying to solve, there should be other and better ways to address. Is there a "presentation layer" where the column headings can be changed instead? If you're just dumping column headings to an Excel file for that file to be populated, that's fine, but if you want to update these columns with SQL later, I think you may be creating yourself work going about it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other wise you can use the "simplified" approach.

```
declare @MonthParam varchar(20) = 'March'
declare @Dte date = CAST(concat(@MonthParam, ' 01 1900') AS DATE)
declare @sql varchar(max) = concat('select null as ', DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Dte)),
                    ', null as ', DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 4, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 5, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 7, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 8, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 9, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 10, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 11, @Dte)),
                    ',null as ',DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 12, @Dte))) 
 exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanx this did exactly what I needed!

Comment: @LeeRoy glad it helped. You can mark it as an answer if it is the option you went with.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date_entered varchar(50) = 'February'
set @date_entered = @date_entered + ' 01 ' + CONVERT(char(4),year(getdate()))
declare @start_month datetime = @date_entered
declare @loop_month datetime = @start_month

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'CREATE TABLE MyDates ('

WHILE @loop_month < DATEADD(year,1,@start_month)
BEGIN
    set @sql += DATENAME(month,@loop_month) + ' varchar(100),'
    set @loop_month = DATEADD(month,1,@loop_month)
END

-- Get rid of the comma at the end of the string and close the table paranthesis (edit was to the following bit)
set @sql = LEFT(@sql,len(@sql)-1) + ')'

print @sql
--Uncomment below to run
--exec(@sql)
```

Comment: The final `set @sql +=` should be just `set @sql =`. I've made the edit, but it won't appear in @ElementZero 's answer until peer reviewed.

Comment: Ah thanks Steve.  I forgot to remove that + when I added the LEFT. :)

Comment: Thank you guys! This looks like it might work, I will test and let you know. Thanks for the support Steve Lovell, Element Zero!

Answer (score 0):

I've used a temp table with some dummy data to show the final output as a table

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @date_entered varchar(50) = 'February';
SET @date_entered = @date_entered + ' 01 ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE()));
DECLARE @s INT= 1, @e INT = 12;
CREATE TABLE PivotTemp (Dummy INT, [MonthName] VARCHAR(15));

WHILE ( @s <= @e)
BEGIN
    SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =
    COALESCE(
        @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, @s, @date_entered)) + ']',
        '[' + DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, @s, @date_entered))+ ']'
    );
    INSERT INTO PivotTemp ( Dummy, [MonthName] )  VALUES ( @s, DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, @s, @date_entered)) );
    SET @s = @s + 1;
END;
--SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders ; 
--SELECT * FROM PivotTemp ;

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      H.Dummy [DummyValue],
      H.[MonthName] [MonthName]
    FROM dbo.PivotTemp H
  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
    MAX(DummyValue)
    FOR [MonthName] IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
';

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL);
DROP TABLE PivotTemp;
```